# How can i create a list just using cons and empty list? Racket

Tags: list, scheme, lisp, racket

Hi have been asked as to build the following lists,just by using cons and the empty list.I attempted to do the first one,i tried this first,for the first list.

```
(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 '())) (cons 3 (cons 2 '())))  this was the output '((1 2) 3 2)
```

i also tried this `(cons (cons 1 '()) (cons (cons 2 '())) (cons 3 (cons 4 '())) '())`

but it kept returning augment errors,can someone explain how should i apply the empty lists and cons to obtain the required results

```
‘(1 (2 ( 3 2 ))) 
 '(1 2 (3 4 (5))) 
 '(((1 2 3))) 
 '((1 (2)) 3 4)
```

Comment: I find it easier to start with `list` (e.g., the first one is `(list 1 (list 2 (list 3 2)))` and the third `(list (list (list 1 2 3)))`) and then rewrite `(list a b ,,, z)` as `(cons a (cons b (... (cons z '())...)`.

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to answer this question is not to: instead *write a program which will answer it for you*: you want a program which, given some object, will return a description of a program which will make it for you.  Here is one such:

```
(define (make-cons-tree-maker tree)
  ;; Note this assumes that the trees are trees.
  (cond
    [(null? tree)
     ;; If the tree is null then it is made by '().  This case is not needed
     ;; (why?)
     '(quote ())]
    [(cons? tree)
     ;; If the tree is a cons we make it by the cons function
     `(cons ,(make-cons-tree-maker (car tree))
            ,(make-cons-tree-maker (cdr tree)))]
    [(symbol? tree)
     ;; Symbols need quoting.  This case is not strictly needed either
     `(quote ,tree)]
    [(or (number? tree)
         (string? tree))
     ;; Numbers and strings do not need quoting
     tree]
    [else
     ;; But assume anything else does (this is safe)
     `(quote ,tree)]))
```

And now

```
> (make-cons-tree-maker '(x y))
'(cons 'x (cons 'y '()))
```

In fact, as the comments in the function say, it can be made a lot simpler, if you are willing to accept that the instructions it returns are not minimal:

```
(define (make-cons-tree-maker tree)
  ;; Note this assumes that the trees are trees.
  (if (cons? tree)
     ;; If the tree is a cons we make it by the cons function
     `(cons ,(make-cons-tree-maker (car tree))
            ,(make-cons-tree-maker (cdr tree)))
     ;; otherwise just quote it
     `(quote ,tree)))
```

This will return the same result for the above tree:

```
> (make-cons-tree-maker '(x y))
'(cons 'x (cons 'y '()))
```

But its result has a lot of unneeded `quote`s for some other trees:

```
> (make-cons-tree-maker '(1 2 3 "foo" . 4))
'(cons '1 (cons '2 (cons '3 (cons '"foo" '4))))
```

And finally you can of course do this, which entertains you if this sort of thing entertains you:

```
> (make-cons-tree-maker '(define (make-cons-tree-maker tree)
                           ;; Note this assumes that the trees are trees.
                           (if (cons? tree)
                               ;; If the tree is a cons we make it by the cons function
                               `(cons ,(make-cons-tree-maker (car tree))
                                      ,(make-cons-tree-maker (cdr tree)))
                               ;; otherwise just quote it
                               `(quote ,tree))))
'(cons
  'define
  (cons
   (cons 'make-cons-tree-maker (cons 'tree '()))
   (cons
    (cons
     'if
     (cons
      (cons 'cons? (cons 'tree '()))
      (cons
       (cons
        'quasiquote
        (cons
         (cons
          'cons
          (cons
           (cons
            'unquote
            (cons
             (cons
              'make-cons-tree-maker
              (cons (cons 'car (cons 'tree '())) '()))
             '()))
           (cons
            (cons
             'unquote
             (cons
              (cons
               'make-cons-tree-maker
               (cons (cons 'cdr (cons 'tree '())) '()))
              '()))
            '())))
         '()))
       (cons
        (cons
         'quasiquote
         (cons (cons 'quote (cons (cons 'unquote (cons 'tree '())) '())) '()))
        '()))))
    '())))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to understand:

- A cons cell is , informally, a kind of container. It contains exactly two things, of any type, respectively its `car` and its `cdr`.
- A list is a specific sequence of nested cons cells. More precisely, a list is a chain of cons, in which the `car` of each cons represents an element of the list, and the `cdr` is either the next link of the chain, or `'()`.

A different formulation: a list is either `'()`, or a cons cell whose `cdr` is a list.

Now, for your problem:

#### First example: `'(1 (2 (3 2)))`

- The first element of this list is `1`. According to what precedes, this means that `1` is the `car` of the first cons cell which makes up the list. Hence, the expression will be of the form `(cons 1 <something>)`.
- The next element of the list is itself a list, namely `(2 (3 2))`. This is also the last element of the list. This means that `<something>` is of the form `(cons '(2 (3 2)) '())`. Indeed, we have seen that a list must end with a cons cell of the form `(cons element '())`; in that case, `element` is somewhat complicated, but you have to stick to the rules ! This means that the full expression will be of the form `(cons 1 (cons '(2 (3 2)) '()))`

We need to "develop" the ugly `'(2 (3 2))` form that we still have in the middle of the previous expression. We just follow the same rules: this is a list, the first element of which is `2`. It can therefore be written as `(cons 2 <rest>)`.

- Its next element is itself a list, namely `'(3 2)`. It also happens to be the last element of the list, so `<rest> == (cons '(3 2) '())`.
- Finally, and still following the same rules, `'(3 2) == (cons 3 (cons 2 '()))`.

Putting everything together, we get that

`'(1 (2 (3 2))) == (cons 1 (cons (cons 2 (cons (cons 3 (cons 2 '())) '())) '()))`

The last expression is confusing and pretty much unreadable, but you can get it by doing things slowly. The important thing is that

```
(a b c d ... z) == (cons a (cons b (cons c ... (cons z '()))))
```

regardless of how complex `a, b ... z` actually are. You can the just apply this "formula" (which is really just the definition of a list as a chain of cons cells), and continue to apply it if your sub-expressions are still lists rather than atoms.

#### Another interesting example: '(((1 2 3)))

This is a list of exactly one element, `'((1 2 3))`. It is therefore written as `(cons <this element> '())` where `<this-element>` is still somewhat complicated.

In particular, `<this-element>` is itself a list ! It is of length 1, and has exactly one element, `'(1 2 3)`. It can therefore be written as `(cons '(1 2 3) '())`

Now, `'(1 2 3)`, by what precedes, is simply `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))`.

So `'((1 2 3))` is just `(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))) '())`

... and finally

```
'(((1 2 3))) == (cons (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))) '()) '())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're learning about pairs and lists, it can be useful to draw a Cons-cell diagrams. There's a great Racket library [Sdraw](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sdraw/index.html), which visualizes given list or pair- so I used it to show you structure of created lists:

```
#lang racket
(require sdraw)

; '(1 (2 (3 2)))
(sdraw (cons 1 (cons (cons 2 (cons (cons 3 (cons 2 '())) '())) '())))
; '(1 2 (3 4 (5)))
(sdraw (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons (cons 3 (cons 4 (cons (cons 5 '()) '()))) '()))))
; '(((1 2 3)))
(sdraw (cons (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))) '()) '()))
; '((1 (2)) 3 4)
(sdraw (cons (cons 1 (cons (cons 2 '()) '())) (cons 3 (cons 4 '()))))
```